# AWS CloudFormation Dynamically Create a Number of Volumes Attached to an EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have been doing some research and have not really found an answer to this. What I would like to do is in CloudFormation, have a parameter that a user can specify a number that would correlate to the number of volumes they would like attached to an EC2 instance when it is brought up. Obviously there will always be the root volume but then any number (up to the max allowed) of volumes could be created and mounted to the specified EC2 instance by the user. Is there a way to accomplish this in CloudFormation? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve? While you could potentially use [conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) to make this work, I think such a stack would be painful to create and maintain. In my experience you'll be _much_ happier creating a single stack for a single (set) of applications, and happier still if you use code generation to create your stacks.

Comment: The more detailed problem I am trying to solve is I want to spin up ElasticSearch (not the AWS version) on an EC2 instance with X number of shards and have each shard be allocated to a different volume. However the number of shards varies making the number of volumes I need vary. I am not familiar with code generation, I'll have to take a look at that.

Comment: FWIW, I use [cfndsl](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cfndsl) to generate CloudFormation stacks. You define the stack as a Ruby script, so you can use loops and variables, so that's where you'd specify the number of volumes (versus a parameter provided at the time the stack is created). If you don't know/don't like Ruby, I know there's an equivalent tool for Python, or it would be simple enough to write a shell script or something in your favorite programming language.

Comment: I do question the need for multiple volumes, however. If you're using EBS, then you automatically get all of the things (well, overlapping seeks, mostly) that people typically turn to multiple volumes to get, and one large volume is generally better from an IOPS perspective (you reduce the likelihood of a hot volume). But I've never set up a "bare metal" ElasticSearch cluster, so you may have reasons that I don't know about.